# How to prevent a link outside a function from triggering it on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems like an easy fix, but can't seem to figure it out.  I have a table that spawns a fixed header whenever you scroll on it.  It's working well, however, an unconnected link near the top of this page, via jquery, scrolls the cursor to the bottom of the page til it hits an anchor.  As a result, it quickly moves over the table, spawning the fixed menu, then after reaching the anchor, the fixed menu awkwardly sits there for a second or two, then disappears.

I'm trying to prevent that by disabling the function on click of the link.  I've tried e.preventDefault (), but no joy.  Here's the fiddle and code (so looking to prevent the fixed "Header / Description" row when you click the link).

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/solracp25/wtmb42n7/1/)**

```
// top edge of table
var element_menu_hdr = $(".row-1").offset().top;
var element_menu_end_check = $(".row-12").offset().top;
$(window).on("scroll", function fixmenu() {
    var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_menu_hdr = element_menu_hdr;
    var scroll_menu_end_check = element_menu_end_check; 
    if(y_scroll_pos >= scroll_menu_hdr) {

if($('.affix').length === 0){
$('.row-1.odd').wrap('<table class="tablemain affix view"></table>');  
}

} else if (y_scroll_pos < scroll_menu_hdr)  {
$('.tablemain.affix.view').contents().unwrap();
} else {    
    }  
});

// bottom edge of table
var element_menu_end = $(".row-12").offset().top;
$(window).on("scroll", function fixmenubtm() {
    var y_scroll_pos2 = window.pageYOffset;
    var scroll_menu_end = element_menu_end;
    if(y_scroll_pos2 > scroll_menu_end) {

$('.tablemain.affix.view tbody').contents().unwrap();   

} else {    
        } 
var myVar = y_scroll_pos2;
console.log(myVar, "y_scroll_pos2");    
var myVar2 = element_menu_end;
console.log(myVar2, "element_menu_end");
});

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top}, 500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Would really help if you could put that up on jsfiddle or something so we could see it. Also, if you could get rid of the image so we don't need to mock out a png.

Comment: Good call, just added the fiddle (w/ stripped down code so it's easier to debug).  Thanks for the tip.